# Using structs for a linked list versus using them for a point-type variable

Tags: c, list, struct

If I want to make a variable Point which can hold 2 doubles and I want to avoid having to write struct everytime I use it I can simply use:

```
typedef struct{
    double x,y; 
}Point;
```

But when I want to make a linked list the declaration must be like this:

```
typedef struct Node Node; // (2)
struct Node{
    int d;
    struct Node * next;   
};
```

And not like this:

```
typedef struct{
    int d;
    struct Node * next;   
}Node;
```

Why does the declaration have to be this way and why do you have to type "Node" twice, see (2).

Comment: It only has be like that (2) when your declared structure uses `Node *next;` (which yours does not). You can just use `struct Node`. Or is the intent to declare the `Node` type in the first place?

Comment: What is the relation between `Point` and `Node`? Update, oh, it's just an example, right?

Comment: Your third option can work, if you give the `struct` a tag: `typedef struct Node{ int d; struct Node * next; } Node;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct Node Node;
```

This statement is the directive to the compiler to consider `Node` to be the same name as `struct Node`, that is why it has to include the word "Node" twice.

Also the declaration doesn't have to be this way, the second version is correct too.

The `struct` declaration doesn't have to include `typedef` at all, it is needed only to assign the type a new name and is often used with `struct` declarations to avoid the need to type the word `struct` over and over.